# Why $\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\log \int_0^1 e^{-nh(x)}dx=-\min_{[0,1]}h$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h$ continuous and bounded. I'm trying to prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\log\int_0^1 e^{-nh(x)}dx=-\min_{[0,1]}h.$$
In the book I'm reading, they say that it's a straightforward exercise, but I'm trying to prove it since couple hours, and I don't see how to do it. The best thing I can do it's since $h$ is bounded and continuous, there are $\alpha,\beta  \in [0,1]$ s.t. $-h(\alpha )\leq -h(x)\leq -h(\beta )$, and thus $$-h(\alpha )\leq \frac{1}{n}\log \int_0^1 e^{-nh(x )}dx\leq -h(\beta )=-\min_{[0,1]}h.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let me write $m$ for minimum of $h$. Let $\epsilon >0$. There exist $x$ such that $h(x) <m+\epsilon$. By continuity there exist an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $h(y) <m+\epsilon$ for all $y \in (a,b)$. Now $\int_0^{1} e^{-nh(t)} dt \geq \int_a^{b} e^{-nh(t)} dt > \int_a^{b} e^{-n(m+\epsilon)} dt=(b-a)e^{-n(m+\epsilon)}  $. Can you finish?